# Android looping runnable increases heap

Tags: java, android, heap-memory

I've created a simple Activity in Android with a Runnable looping infinitely. The heap will keep increasing until a GC_CONCURRENT is thrown out. Is this normal behaviour or should I change the way I code it?

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Runnable {

    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_id);
        textView.setText(R.string.hello_world);

        TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_id2);
        textView2.setText(R.string.hello_world);

        TextView textView3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_id3);
        textView3.setText(R.string.hello_world);

        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
}
```

So I have 3 TextViews and I just want to call a runnable to update the texts shown (here I put resource strings but it could be any string). I'm not looking at memory leak when I rotate the tablet (for that I should use WeakReference or remove the callback on onDestroy()). I just don't understand why the heap is increasing and nothing is GCed. Once the runnable is executed it should be garbage collected and if the UI can refresh quicker than 100ms the heap should stop increasing.

Thanks for your help,
JB

Comment: "here I put resource strings but it could be any string" -- that could have a very substantial impact on your memory consumption. "Once the runnable is executed it should be garbage collected" -- no, because you are re-registering it right away. BTW, you don't need a `Handler`, as you can call `postDelayed()` on any one of your `TextView` objects. "I just don't understand why the heap is increasing" -- just because you are not explicitly creating Java objects here does not mean that the framework, in calls like `setText()`, are not creating Java objects.

Comment: Great answer by @CommonsWare.  This is why you need to actually understand frameworks, rather than just use them and blindly hope they'll work.  In addition, you should never assume that something will be GCed as soon as it is unused-  it will almost NEVER be.  The point is that it will be cleaned up at some point later, which could be minutes or even days.  That's the reason why Java doesn't have real destructors.  It will be cleaned up the next time the GC feels like it.  Its safer to assume it will NEVER be cleaned up than to assume it will be in a timely fashion.

Comment: In addition, I can tell you that setText absolutely creates objects in the framework that would need to be GCed, and postHandler can (if the message pool runs out, or if a bug prevents the recycling of message objects).  In fact postHandler caused so many problems that they reuse the Message objects rather than allocate them on the fly and let them be gced.

Comment: I think it'd be better to have a static inner class that implements Runnable and holds a WeakReference to your outer Activity.  It's difficult to write code like you've written and not leak a Context (Activity) which this will currently do.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your answers. I'm going to look into the code of setText() to understand how it works. Gabe if I can't predict when GC occurs, is it bad to wait that the heap fills up until I get GC_CONCURRENT because in the end it doesn't crash my app?